# Percona storage engine in Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, percona, xtradb

I'm using Percona Server with XtraDB, but in Workbench I see the storage engine of the tables is InnoDB.

How can I configure the server to use XtraDB?

Comment: Percona Server is just a fork/drop in replacement off MySQL i believe so i guess this will help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engine-setting.html Otherwise https://learn.percona.com/download-percona-server-5-7-manual

Comment: Technically, Percona Server is not a fork; it is a rebase. MariaDB is a fork.

Answer (score 1):

That answer my question:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/diagnostics/show_engines.html

Storage engine name is InnoDB, but in Comment column I can see "Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys"

Comment: In Percona Server, you cannot use XtraDB and InnoDB at the same time. Creating with ENGINE=InnoDB or ENGINE=XtraDB will always result in XtraDB when running Percona. Additionally, Percona reports the engine name as InnoDB to maintain 'drop-in' and 'drop-out' compatibility.